# Consolidated Cash Flow Statement Yahoo Finance Reliable?

Tags: accounting

this is the first time posting a question as you'll notice I am a bit of a novice in Accounting. I'm grappling with the idea of disregarding financial statements from Yahoo Finance in my decision-making process (which I use to track and research stock holdings). I've recently run across a cash flow statement which did not add up (or with high possibility, I couldn't balance it). The CFS is attached as a screenshot below. I am trying to figure out how Yahoo computed the "cash at the end of the period" without accounting for finance activities. It is very concise (confusing) for "beginners", I have concluded it might be an "indirect method of accounting"? Though I have checked the original company report and their conclusions are the same but the method in which they arrived at the conclusions is quite different. The company financials were way easier and "comprehensible", to keep this short, is yahoo using a reliable method of reporting based on the screenshot? attached a link if required thank you!

n.b fiscal year - 31/12/2019
[Astrazeneca plc](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AZN.L/cash-flow?p=AZN.L)

[image: CFS Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The value that Yahoo Finance adds is not in its precision - it's the fact that is compiles statements from thousands of companies and "normalizes" them, since not all companies use the same buckets in their financials. Yes, mistakes can be made (there are several questions in this forum that deals with mistakes on financial web sites) but it's a risk that some may be willing to take for the benefit of volume.

If you can get the data that you need from the individual companies, then that will be the most accurate source, but you will end up spending time normalizing the statements.